# How to display a div dynamically using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a div that works as loader animation. I have to display it when a checkbox is clicked, but I can't do it. I see other posts about that, but none of thesolutions worked for me.

```js
$('#checker').click(function() {
  const picture = "..."
//  picture = webcam.snap();
//  alert(picture);
  $('#lds-ring').show();
  $.post('TestCamera', {
    param: picture
  }, function(response) {
    if (response === 'error') {
      alert('Abbiamo rilevato un errore rileggi attentamente le istruzioni');
    } else {
      window.location.replace('QuestionAndAnalyze.jsp'); /* redirect*/
    }

  }); /*END servletCall*/
}); /*END click*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column load">
  <div class="lds-ring" style="display:none;">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>



<input type="checkbox" name="checkVision" id="checker">
<label for="checkVision">I read all</label>
```

I followed old posts about this problem and the solution "show()" doesn't work for me.

I tried also:

```
   <div class="lds-ring" style="visibility:hidden;"> </div>
   $('#lds-ring').css('visibility','visible')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$(".lds-ring").show()` - it is a class (`.`) not an ID (`#`)
- `for="checkVision"` should be `for="checker"` - the for takes an ID, not a name
- You can toggle based on the checkbox being checked or not

```js
$('#checker').click(function() {
  $('.lds-ring').toggle(this.checked);
}); /*END click*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkVision" id="checker">
<label for="checker">I read all</label>

<div class="column load">
  <div class="lds-ring" style="display:none;">Hello
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I personally prefer to wrap the box in the label

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkVision" id="checker">I read all</label>
```